# NSArray BAD ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to do a pickerView but I'm getting bad acess:

here is my code

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    list = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    [self populateList]
}

-(void) populateList {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameoffile" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    list = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
}


 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     return (NSString *)[list objectAtIndex:row]; //here I'm getting bad acces
 }
```

The error is: **"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xa001cc65)"**

Comment: Please post the (symbolic) stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: OK add this before the line with the error: `NSAssert(row < [list count], @"Row %d is out-of-range", row);` and re-run your app.

Comment: @trojanfoe Won't help much. This is a segfault, not an NSException.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah but you should be able to get a stacktrace from lldb using `bt`?

Comment: @illDev: Are you sure pickerView:titleForRow is getting called only after list gets populate?

Comment: What you have in viewWillAppear - try moving that to viewDidLoad. Or at least ensure that list is allocated and initialized in viewDidLoad or initWith...

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` returned by `componentsSeparatedByString:` is autoreleased value so you need to retain it.

You should remove:

```
list = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

and add retain to:

```
list = [[file componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] retain];
```

Comment: then he sould use `strong` property.

Comment: And how do you know he's not?